# Troubleshooting Elasticsearch returning unstable results. Can I query only a particular node in the cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am querying Elasticsearch every 30 minutes for some count of events collected in the last 30 minutes. And I am expecting results ranging from `6` to `8`. But from time to time Elasticsearch returns `0` which is a false query result. (I am seeing the events in Kibana and there is no deviation from the range `6-8` messages per 30 minutes).

The query ran for months correctly with no false results and 1 week ago it started to return the incorrect results.

I am using Elasticsearch version `7.3.1`.

**What I have researched so far**

**Were there any Elasticsearch upgrades/patches around the time it started?** The service provider told me there were not.

**Was there in increase in Elasticsearch usage (ingestion/queries)?** I see no deviation from the last month averages.

**Is the status of the cluster green?** Yes, the cluster is in green health status.

**Are all the indexes having a green status?** Yes, all the indexes have the green health status.

Here is my query:

```
POST /*parsed*/_search?size=0&filter_path=hits.total.value
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "app": {
              "query": "billing-processor"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": {
              "query": "BillingRecords and finished"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "now-30m",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The Elasticsearch cluster has 3 nodes (all with all 3 roles:`ingest`, `master`, `data`) and replication factor 2 for index shards.

I came to analyse the Elasticsearch cluster node advanced analytics and I see these suspicious JVM Heap charts for 2 of the nodes:

[image: node instance-0000000000]

[image: node instance-0000000002]

(the 3rd node has a very smooth chart)

And these are the times when the query returned false results (blue dots) compared to all executions (green bars):

[image]

I am suspecting that when the query hits a certain node, the query result is sometimes incorrect while for other nodes the query is always correct.

**Question**: How can I query only a particular node of Elasticsearch? (the cluster is provided as a service and I am only exposed a load balancer FQDN for the cluster: `https://182a33a5c22a4db7840457a555773ed5.elasticsearch.my-service-provider.net`). Can I provide hints in the query or request metadata that I want my results delivered by a certain node?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the answer in the Elasticsearch documentation: [Search shard routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-shard-routing.html).

The `routing` query parameter can be provided in the `_search` requests:

```json
POST /my-index-000001/_doc?routing=my-routing-value
{
  "@timestamp": "2099-11-15T13:12:00",
  "message": "GET /search HTTP/1.1 200 1070000",
  "user": {
    "id": "kimchy"
  }
}
```

Still, in the particular issue mentioned in the question, it comes more and more to the surface that the node/index caching might be cause the issue. The search query uses **`size=0` which is apparently treated in a special way by Elasticsearch**. The hints are given in the documentation of the `_search` `request_cache` query parameter:

> (Optional, Boolean) If `true`, the caching of search results is enabled for requests where **`size` is 0**. See Shard request cache settings. Defaults to index level settings.

and in the [Shard request cache settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/shard-request-cache.html#shard-request-cache) documentation page:

> By default, the requests cache will only cache the results of search requests where **`size=0`**, so it will not cache `hits`, but it will cache `hits.total`, aggregations, and suggestions.
>
> Most queries that use now (see Date Math) cannot be cached.
>
> Scripted queries that use the API calls which are non-deterministic, such as Math.random() or new Date() are not cached.